# Should I capititalize “Crime Science”?

Tags: orthography, capitalization

Not sure if I should use *crime science* or *Crime Science* throughout my essay.
When should I capitalize the term?

Comment: The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crime_science) page doesn't. Except when talking about certain specific organizations.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. There is an excellent answer in the above site. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Use lower case with a few exceptions:

At the beginning of a sentence or quotation or as part of a title "I titled my paper 'Crime Science' because ..."

As the name of a specific course: Crime Science 101 (but "I took a course on crime science.")

As part of an industry-wide standard: Boston Crime Science is unique because ...

Or, as part of an organization (as above), like the Illinois Crime Science Association